# Communicate from PC to Mobile

Tags: android, bluetooth, windows-10

I'd like to build a communication system that includes a windows 10 PC application that will connect on a Mobile device application and exchange data between the 2.

The idea is I've got a electronic box who do some specific measurements. This box is composed of some USB and GPIB(National Instruments) devices. This box is actually controlled using a Visual Basic.Net application that I made (working well). But i'd like to to push it further and remote that application from a mobile device such a phone or tablet. That means the mobile device would send a command to my PC application saying to start measurement and ones the measurement is done my PC application would send back the results to my mobile device to display the result of the measurement.

So if i'm right I need to make my PC application listening and waiting for a connection with the mobile and than, when this is connected, the PC and Mobile application can talk to each other.

I would like the connection between the PC and the mobile to be wireless (if possible). I was thinking about the Bluetooth, but I've go no idea if this is feasible. If Bluetooth would be possible avenue, can you please tell me were I can get the information how I could program it using VB or C#. if this is not doable can I physically connect the Mobile to PC with a USB cable and do my communication that way? if both avenue are possible which way is easiest?

has you can understand I will also have to create a mobile app which I never did but I guess I can figure this out. I'm also guessing that my mobile application will be more likely to be android since IOS is pretty closed.

Anything would help! thanks everyone.

Comment: How about use wifi, you can build a socket server application on pc, and mobile app as socket client, you can use tcp or udp to communicate each other.

Comment: There are few ways to do what you need: 1. Use Bluetooth; 2. Use WiFi Direct; 3. Use WiFi Soft AP. Bluetooth is more p2p communication. WFD is also p2p. SoftAP allows to connect few devices to single PC(or mobile, depends what will act as AP).